# Monotouch back to first ViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, xamarin.ios, uitabbar

I'm having a problem going back again to my first Apps VC, the first "screen/ViewController)" is a login screen, then I call a UITabbar with their respective ViewControllers, when I'm on a certain level of a ViewController (for example the 5th one) I want to get a "Logout" behavior in my App and get back to the first ViewController (Login). But I think I can only Navigate back to the first ViewController of my Tabbar control. I was trying with this methods of my VC:

this.NavigationController.PopToViewController(previousVC,true);
or
this.NavigationController.PopToRootViewController(true);

Any help would be appreciated.

(If you need more details with the code please tell me about it)

```
    //Call to the tab bar from the login viewcontroller
    mainTBC = new TabBarMenuPpal ();
this.NavigationController.PushViewController (mainTBC, true);
…

//Tabbarmenuppal with a set of navcontrollers 
public TabBarMenuPpal ()
{
    var customerVC = new Customers ();
    navCustomers = new UINavigationController ();
    navCustomers.PushViewController (customerVC, true);
    navCustomers.TopViewController.Title = customersTitle;
    navCustomers.TabBarItem = new UITabBarItem (customersTitle, UIImage.FromFile ("Utility/Images/Cust-30x30.png"), 0);
    …
    mainVC = new UIViewController[]
    {
          navCustomers
        , navSettings
    } ;
    this.ViewControllers = mainVC;
}
```

The problem is that when I start to navigate in the navCustomers I can't find a way to go back to the login VC (deleting my tab bar and releasing all their resources). (Sorry about my English).

Comment: Can you show code for your specific setup? Are you using UITabBarController or UINavigationController?

Comment: Broadly speaking, you probably need to have a method exposed on your AppDelegate that will clean up the tabs, navbars and views and then display your login UI.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the best solution but I have implemented a "GoToLogin" method in my UITabBarController which only does this:

```
public void GoToLogin()
{
   this.NavigationController.PopToRootViewController(true);
}
```

So when I need to go to my first page I only do this:

```
if(MainDialog.NavigationController.TabBarController != null)//loaded from the tab bar
              ((TabBarMenuPpal)MainDialog.NavigationController.TabBarController).GoToLogin();
else//loaded from the login screen  
              MainDialog.NavigationController.PopToRootViewController(true);
```